# Go to Previous URL issue?

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I have used the `document.referrer` comment to get the previous url of the page. When I click the menus `document.referrer` is redirecting properly. However when I paste the URLs it returns `undefined`.

```
$('.page ul li:first a').attr('href', document.referrer);
```

Above is the jQuery code I used in my site. How can I sort out this issue?

Comment: You code should work, so we kinda need to get some more information or code in order to help you find the problem

Comment: If you paste/enter a new URL in to the search bar then there is no referrer. There's no workaround for that.

Comment: Please explain "when i pasting the urls"

Comment: Use History library to handle prev and history